# Dynamically change the catalog name in hibernate entity for sql server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I have different databases(more than 20) with same table structures. Can I use a single entity object and change the catalog(database name) to the file dynamically.

thanks in advance

Comment: could you explain deeper what is the catalog?

Comment: Catalog is the database name in sqlserver

Comment: as I understood you want to change DB at runtime?

Comment: Yes. That is correct @idmitriev

Answer (score 0):

You can create and change a datasource at runtime. If you have two different DBs with the same tables you can create two different datasources that linked to different databases and use `Multi-tenancy` - https://www.ricston.com/blog/multitenancy-jpa-spring-hibernate-part-1/.
Or you can google it - `hibernate multi tenancy`